# How to allow adding only specific items to a subgrid

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a subgrid of account items and I want to allow **adding** ONLY specific items to the subgrid
 - not just to filter the **display** of items on the subgrid.
Is this in any way possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Specific in what way? Related to the parent record somehow, or having some particular property?

You could add a N:1 relationship (the opposite of what you have now) then use a lookup with a custom filtered view to allow the user to select a record then use javascript to update that record with this one as it's parent to make it a child, then clear the lookup to go round again.

Comment: Hi. It should be filtered according to a specific property (equal to a certain value). There's already a view that filters it, but I want to make it the default (and only) view that open from the "Add Existing" button. Also, the relationship is N:N so it has to be done from a subgrid.